# Снижает ли вложенный namespace производительность?

Tags: c#, namespace

Снижается ли производительность от сильно вложенных пространств имён? Если да, то сколько циклов процессора съедает каждое вложение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, не снижается. Пространства имен существуют только до компиляции и служат исключительно для безопасной организации кода.

После того как JIT компилирует код для выполнения, пространства имен как и сами имена, перестают существовать.

Доступ к именам и прочим атрибутам структуры кода во время выполнения возможен только через рефлексию, но всем известно, что она сама по себе медленная и пара лишних точек в пути до типа погоды не сделает.

Comment: То есть точки в пути всё-таки вычисляются.

Comment: @AlexeyLot только при использовании рефлексии. И если оно и влияет, вы это никогда не заметите, потому что влияние будет в рамках статистической погрешности измерений.

Comment: @AlexeyLot точки в пути не вычисляются, они просто являются частью имени, как другие символы. Даже при reflection. Никакого оверхеда там нет, перестаньте экономить на символах.

Comment: @PashaPash все так. Я как раз имел в виду тот факт, что если оверхед и есть, то его невозможно обнаружить.

Comment: @aepot это скорее коммент для топикастера был - он, похоже, решил что именно точки как-то особо «вычисляются»