# Повышает ли потребление ОЗУ и циклов ЦП использование множества разных одинаковых по содержанию типов с разными именами?

Tags: c#, производительность

Повышает ли потребление ОЗУ и циклов ЦП использование множества разных одинаковых по содержанию типов с разными именами вместо одного общего типа? Например, если у нас есть несколько DTO для передачи сообщений внутри пограммы, но они отличаются только своими именами и именами членов, но типы в них полностью идентичны, то будет ли программа потреблять больше ресурсов по сравнению с тем, если бы для программы использовался один DTO такого типа?

Comment: думаю что будет немного больше т.к. прийдется приводить типы для работы с ними все равно к реальным типам. Ну то есть допустим все типы в программе ты будешь использовать Object. Но что бы сделать действие с интом - тебе обджект все равно будет необходимо привести к инту. Хоть для чтения - хоть для изменения. Ну а если и не читать и не изменять - то тогда разницы быть не должно никакой по логике.

Comment: данный вопрос звучит где то так - если я на машине буду поворачивать только вправо, увеличится ли потребления топлива? - то есть, в вопросе сравниваются процессы/вещи, которые находятся на слишком разных уровнях. Оптимизаторы сейчас могут творить такое, что ух. так что только профилирование конкретного кода сможет ответить на вопрос.

Comment: @KoVadim вообще данный участник задаёт второй подобный вопрос. Первый тут:
 
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1387816/191482  ... То ли черезчур заморачивается и занимается преждевременной оптимизацией, то ли пришёл из чистого СИ))

Comment: Если такой вопрос уже был, то, пожалуйста, приведите ссылку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Любой объект потребляет память до тех пор, пока не будет уничтожен Сборщиком мусора.

Аллокация объекта так же потребляет время процессора, как и его уничтожение, но последним почти всегда можно пренебречь.

Типы при этом не имеют значения. Если речь про оверхед при обслуживании объектов, то можно считать, что например создание 100 объектов из 100 типов потребляет столько же ресурсов, сколько создание 100 объектов 1 типа.

---

Но вопрос странный, берите **Benchmark.NET** и тестируйте конкретную свою ситуацию. Я рассуждал только о зависимости производительности окружения от количества использованных типов, но не могу спроецировать проблему на реальный мир. Чаще всего если у мне нужен 1 тип, у меня 1 тип. Если мне нужно 2 типа - у меня 2 типа. Как можно себе представить, что мне нужно 100 типов, но у меня 1? Никак, это всего-лишь может означать, что надо написать еще 99.

Comment: То есть само по себе объявление типа класса или структуры ключевыми словами struct, class без их использования в программе никаких ресурсов при выполнении не потребляет?

Comment: По моему,  объявление типа класса или структуры влияет только на объем бинарника. Затраты ресурсов начинаются только при использовании. Причем, если вы объявите, но не будете использовать - у вас будет warning о неиспользуемой переменной